# Can i change the default view of OptionsMenu in android

Tags: android

Android 2.3.3

I have an OptionsMenu. There are 5 - 6(not yet decided exactly) items in it.

The default view of OptionsMenu

1 2 3

4 5 6

Can I change this, so that they appear, one after the another, with 1 item in each row?

If yes, please let me know how.

If No, why? (Is it a standard and cannot be changed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I change this, so that they appear, one after the another, with 1 item in each row?

I don't know of anyway to change the built-in Options Menu like this.

The overflow Options Menu is exactly what you want (add a 7th item to your menu and click "More" to see it.) But you cannot use the overflow menu by itself, you must have the regular menu first...

You could possibly design your own menu, but this might be complicated and require a lot of work.

Comment: Ok. I will go with what the experts say :( Hope we could get access to this in the future..